# How many idioms can you find using the word "word"?

Tags: idioms

For Eg: "have a word" means "to talk briefly".

Comment: You tell me first which ones you know already, then I'll find some more.  For a dime apiece.

Comment: @ deadrat has already listed down a few, I don't think I know beyond them. Are there anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous idiom lists online.  [Here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/word)'s one.  Here's another:

*Buzz word*. specialized slang.

> "Self-actualization" is a buzz word for self-help gurus.

*A dirty word*, a word for something disapproved

> "Fracking" has become **a dirty word** to environmentalists.

*Four-letter words*, obscenities

*He doesn't have a good (or kind) word for anybody.*  He's generally unpleasant.

*A man of few words.*  Someone who speaks little.
*A man of his word.*  Someone who can be trusted.
*A play on words or word play*.  A joke depending on double meanings or sound-alikes

> The dog grooming service has a name that's a **play on words.**  It's
>   called "The Barking Lot."

*A war of words.*  An argument
*A word to the wise*.  Take a hint.
*Actions speak louder than words.*  Talk is cheap; deeds are the standard for judgment.
*As good as his word*.  He's trustworthy.
*I'm at a loss for words.*  So surprised that I'm pretending I can't speak.
*Have the last word*.  Win the dispute.
*I don't believe a word of it*.  It's completely false.
*It's beyond words*.  Very amazing.
*Break one's word, go back on one's word.* Renege on a promise.
*Don't breathe a word.*  Keep a secret.
*Word of mouth*.  Spread by rumor.
*Exchange more than ... words with*.  Not know very well.

> I don't know what he likes.  I haven't exchanged **more than two words**
>   **with** him all year.

*Eat one's words.*  Acknowledge that one is wrong.
*Famous last words*. An ironic reference to an epitaph.

> He said that his boss would appreciate his criticism -- **famous last**
>   **words**.

*Fighting words.*  A dire insult.
*For want of a better word*.  Acknowledging, sometimes ironically, that a particular word isn't completely apt.

> Let's just say that they couple is getting divorced because they are
>   incompatible, **for want of a better word**.

*From the word go*.  From the beginning.
*Can't get a word in edgeways (or edgewise)*.  Locked out of a conversation by someone garrulous.

*The last word in*.  The ultimate.

> The Apple Watch is **the last word in** electronic gadgets.

*Get the word.*  Be informed.
*Give (or say) the word*.  Approve the start of an action.
*Hang on every word*.  Pay rapt attention.
*Sticks and stones may break my bones, but words will never hurt me.*  Insults are without force.
*Put a word in you ear.*  Tell you something confidential.
*Have a word with.*  Talk to.
*I have no words for.*  Something indescribable, usually bad.
*The words stick in my throat (or craw)*.  Something difficult to admit.
*In a word*.  Briefly.
*In other words.*  Alternatively.
*In so many words*, word for word.  Literally.
*In words of one syllable*.  Simply.
*Keep one's word*.  Keep one's promise.
Leave word for.  Leave a message.
*Many a true word is spoken in jest*.  Just because I'm joking doesn't mean what I said isn't true.
*Mark my word(s)*. Remember what I say

> You'll be sorry if you don't go.  **Mark my words.**

*Don't mince words*.  Say directly.
*Mum's the word, Don't breathe a word.*  Keep a secret.
*My word is my bond, I'm as good as my word.*  You can trust what I say.
*Or words to that effect*.  I'm paraphrasing.
*A picture is worth a thousand words*.  An image is better than a description.
*Put in a good word*.  Say something nice on the behalf of another.
*It's hard to put into words*.  Difficult to describe.
*Don't put words in my mouth*.  I didn't say that and don't claim that I did.
*Receive word*.  Be informed.
*Let me say a few words*.  I'm going to give a short speech.
*Send word to*.  Tell someone.
*Spread the word*.  Make known.
*Swallow one's words*.  Repress what one wants to say.
*Take him at his word, take his word for it*.  Believe what he says.
*Took the words (right) out of my mouth*.  Repeated what I would have said.
*The operative word.*  The important thing.
*Too funny for words*.  Extremely humorous.
*Don't twist my words*.  Don't misrepresent me.
*My word!*  A mild exclamation.

> **My word!**  What a beautiful dress!

*Don't utter a word.*  Stop talking.
*Weasel words.*  Words intended to deceive without being an outright lie.
*Weigh one's words carefully*.  Speak cautiously and deliberately.
*What’s the word?*  What's up?
*I won't hear a word against her.*  Don't talk badly about her.
*His word is law.*  What he says happens.
*Give my word of honor.* I promise.
*Words to live by*.  Good tenets.
*It's your word against his.*  The only evidence are the two accounts, yours and his.

Comment: You left out: to have [a word in your shell-like ear](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/414550.html). :P